# GKLocalPlayer getting profile pictures

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, gamekit, game-center

I'm working with Game Center Kit, how can I get the image of game center user(my friend, or anyone else) thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an asynchronous method to load either a small or normal sized player image (only available in iOS5):

```
- (void)loadPhotoForSize:(GKPhotoSize)size 
   withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *photo, NSError *error))completionHandler
```

Comment: I was try to do it in IOs 4.3... So Thanks for the answer.